# xcode 7: error: editor placeholder in source file

Tags: xcode, swift2, ios9, xcode7

I am trying to create a button on apple maps that will relocate the user if he or she navigates elsewhere.
I found some old solutions to this problem for like ios 7 or 8 which no longer worked in ios 9. This is what I tried

```
@IBAction func locateMe(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.mapView.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode, animated: true)

}
```

there are no errors before I try to run it but when I do it says: editor placeholder in source file

Comment: The title of this question and the marked answer don't appear to match.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't solve the bug issue, But i did realize how easy it was to get the re auto locate button to work. The code that I used to initially get the auto location just needs to be copied and pasted into the button action brackets and will rerun the code when tapped.

Comment: The title of this question and the marked answer don't appear to match.